# Create macro - find, capture, delete

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've researched & tried for a couple hours now to create a Macro. For my entire document, I want to: 1. Search for "Author:" 2. Capture "Author:" and the entire remaining paragraph. 3. Delete it.
I've combined different codes for each individual function, and all variations consistently delete "Author:" but not the remaining paragraph. My last attempt:

```
Sub FindDeleteAuthor()

With Selection.Find

.ClearFormatting

.Text = "Author:"
'
'
    Selection.Extend
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
    Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1

.Forward = True

.Wrap = wdFindContinue

.Format = False

.MatchCase = False

.MatchWholeWord = False

.MatchWildcards = False

.MatchSoundsLike = False

.MatchAllWordForms = False

.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

End With

End Sub
```

My coding skills are embryonic-beginner, at best. So any help would be seriously appreciated ... especially if provided in the most greenest, novice way.
Also, is there a good, 1-stop site or resource on creating specific Macros for Word? I'm currently in a painful, hazing-conversion period from WordPerfect to Word. Big, big sigh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's as simple as:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Text = "Author:*^13"
  .Replacement.Text = "^p"
  .Forward = True
  .Format = False
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  .MatchWildcards = True
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this! ... When I run it, a popup msg comes up with the very next paragraph with the found words "Author: ..." all in the popup msg. Then when I click "OK," it will select the next "Author:" paragraph & delete it but won't loop to find & delete all of them.

Comment: You said you wanted to capture the found string, but you haven't said what you want to do with it once you've captured it. Please explain. Then I'll update the code to process multiple instances.

Comment: My apologies ... I want to "select" each found string (entire paragraph after "Author:") and then delete it. I just discovered capture may have a different meaning in coding? Thank you again for your help.

Comment: There is no need to *select* anything. See the revised code. You don't even need a macro for something so simple!

Comment: Yowza! It worked!!! There were 300+ occurrences that were deleted. I'll be using this for countless documents in the future so this was a lifesaver. You mentioned I didn't need a macro. Is there an easily understood way of accomplishing this wo using a macro?

Comment: Simply use a *wildcard* Find/Replace, where: Find = Author:*^13 Replace = ^p

Comment: Just researched F/R using special characters. This F/R worked as well as 2 other similar F/Rs. Can’t express how much time & near-tears frustration that I was spared with your help. Thanks again!